# Why does Docker -u doesnt work in my server?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, server

I add a User local in my Server with: `adduser name -g 1002` and then I'd like to run my docker with this User so I make: `docker run -v /home/user:/some -u "uid:gid" image` there couldn't find The user: getpwuid() Not found in Passwd.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did your `adduser` command work for you?  Following your pattern, I've created a user with useradd instead of adduser:

```
useradd -m -d /home/name -s /bin/bash -g 1002 name
```

Assuming that the group with ID 1002 already exists on your system, the following docker command should work for you as well:

```
docker run -v /home/name:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -p 8080:80 -d nginx
95e38e96b6b1fdfbf18aece7ccb3c3486db5dc1b142f60515076d8d49fc815f6
```